# Peewee doesn't do MYSQL Transactions at all - am I doing something wrong?

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I am trying to implement simple transactions into my peewee python code.

At first I was using db.atomic() but I was arriving at deadlocks, if two different callbacks would happen (the app runs using acyncio).

The code would be:

```
try:
    with db.atomic() as transaction:
        ...do stuff with multiple tables...
except Exception as e:
    transaction.rollback()
    raise e
```

I then tried switching to db.transaction() and it seemed to help. The problem was gone.

However, now it's back

Basically, peewe says db.transaction() should start a transaction. Yet it does not! I've turned on the logger, and nothing happens when         with db.atomic() as transaction or with db.transaction() as transaction is called! It doesn't execute "START TRANSACTION". Even though it is supposed to?

Or am I doing this wrong?

How can I do proper transactions using peewee - meaning, it won't deadlock, because when I tell it to, it actually calls START TRANSACTION and other processes have to wait until it's done?

Comment: The use of `atomic()` was likely correct and your use of `transaction()` is wrong. You will probably want to put a lock around those blocks in your async code or run them synchronously. See the note at the bottom of the docs re: transaction http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#explicit-transaction

Comment: Also your example code is incorrect, as `transaction` should not be in scope in your `except` block.

Comment: @coleifer I would love to put a lock around it but many different apps access the database
The original issue with atomic() was when I tried locks and found out you can't use locks in multiple apps (obviously) because each app has its own lock
There is also another issue - I can't share a lock object with all places in code which access same database tables

Answer (score 0):

MySQL `transaction` works just fine and is thoroughly covered by unit-tests, but just to demonstrate, this code runs without any errors:

```
db = MySQLDatabase('peewee_test')

class Reg(db.Model):
    value = IntegerField()

db.create_tables([Reg])

with db.transaction() as txn:
    Reg.create(value=1)  # This will commit.

with db.transaction() as txn:
    Reg.create(value=2)
    txn.rollback()  # Explicit rollback.

try:
    with db.transaction() as txn:
        Reg.create(value=3)
        raise ValueError('abort')  # Implicit rollback.
except ValueError:
    pass

assert Reg.select().count() == 1
assert Reg.get().value == 1

db.drop_tables([Reg])
```

Comment: Yes, issue happens if you run async code where one transaction does 1.create 2.create, and another 2.create 1.create. A deadlock happens while it should not, because transaction is supposed to START TRANSACTION which is supposed to make other code attempting DB access to wait

Comment: You're wrong about that. Starting a transaction with the python db drivers will not block.